# How to insert several lists into sqlite column

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, insert-into

I am going to insert information from the following list into sqlite column:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['MAR', 'PAR', 'ZAR']
c = [1000, 2000, 3000]
```

column AA of database should have information in  list a, column BB should have information in list b, and column CC should have information in list c.

This is my code:

```
import sqlite3
conn= sqlite3.connect('test.db') 
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table ():     
    c.execute ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (AA INT, BB TEXT, CC INT)')
    print ("table was created")

create_table ()

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['MAR', 'PAR', 'ZAR']
c= [1000, 2000, 3000]

for i in range (len (a)):
    I= a[i]
    II= b[i]
    III= c[i]
    c.execute  ("INSERT INTO TEST (AA, BB, CC) VALUES  (?,?,?) ", I, II, III )
```

The error is this:

```
c.execute  ("INSERT INTO TEST (AA, BB, CC) VALUES  (?,?,?) ", I, II, III )
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shadowed the `c` variable. It does not refer to the opened cursor anymore:

```
c = conn.cursor()
# ...
c = [1000, 2000, 3000]
```

This is one of the many reasons to have *meaningful variable names*. I doubt you would have made this error if you named the cursor as `cursor`:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

---

Also note, that the modern IDEs like PyCharm are capable of catching these errors early:

[image]